# Matlab: 2d cell array assignment

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I want to create a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is of length 10. For each array in the first dimension, the length of the second dimension is unknown. So, I use a cell array to create this:

```
c = cell(1, 10)
```

Now, suppose I want to add one element, for example the value `6`, to the array in the first dimension. What command do I type? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *append* an element to the first cell array:

```
>> c = cell(1, 10);
>> c{1}{end+1} = 6
```

Initially, when `c{1}` is empty, this gives

```
>> c{1}
ans = 
    [6]
```

Now, to append a (second) element, do the same

```
>> c{1}{end+1} = 7
```

which now gives

```
>> c{1}
ans = 
    [6]    [7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access a particular cell using : `{}`

If you want to add `6` you can do :

> c{1} = 6

It is also possible to do :

> c(1) = {6}

You can look at [Access Data in a Cell Array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) if you need more explanations.